# Android. Can't decode Bitmap from stream

Tags: android, image, inputstream

I have URL to PNG image file.
I want to get this image file and set it as a source for an ImageView.
My code:

```
URL iconURL = null;
try {
    iconURL = new URL("https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/worship_general-71.png");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Bitmap icon = null;
try {
    icon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iconURL.openConnection().getInputStream());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

myImageView.setImageBitmap(icon);
```

If I place a breakpoint into the line with `decodeStream()` the app stops and I see the following:

[image]

If I run the app in regular mode, it just stops!
Can someone explain what is wrong here and how to do it correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add the stacktrace of the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to show the image on your ImageView then you can use Picasso Library.

Put below dependency in build.gradle file

```
'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

And use below java code for loading your image from URL to your ImageView

> Picasso.get()
>                       .load(url)
>                       .into(imageView);